# requestLocationUpdates to get updates when some distance changed/travelled

Tags: android, gps

I need to use requestLocationUpdates() to get location update when some specified distance traveled or for some particular distance.

I need this to be updated on distance basis only and not time basis.

Please suggest....

Comment: have you got your solution? to receive update  only if distance change , not time basis ..

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation has a good answer.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

> public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime,
>   float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
>
> If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted
>   if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as
>   frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.

The location change will be detected by `OnLocationChange()` called by the `LocationListener` registered at `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.....   but I need to be notified when my location changed with some amount regardless of frequent update i.e minTime parameter.....   for example when my location changed by 100 meters.... please provide some example if possible.... thanks

Comment: If you want to detect only a minimum distance, than you need to specify a minDistance. The only way to know the exact distance between Locations is to record the last Location. Then you can use Location.distanceBetween() to know the exact delta.

Comment: so we can not get this task to be done using requestLocationUpdates()....   I am really confused here.  please guide

Comment: this is an easy task and all the answers are in the comments and answer above. The location is received in OnLocationChange(). By storing the location in this method, the next time the method is called, you can compare the locations with distanceTo(). If you do not properly understand how to obtain user location, please see the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the time delay in between location requests just specify it as 0. This way it is 0 seconds delay which really means no delay.

```
LocationManager yourLoc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
yourLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, onLocationChange);
```

The above example changes at every 1m.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the minTime parameter to max value of an Integer or float in java, that way it will get called by minDistance prior to minTime